# NMEA Regex matching: Invalid preceding regular expression error

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to match the following NMEA string

```
$GPRMC,092751.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3371,W,0.06,31.66,280511,,,A*45
```

I wrote and tested a regex in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/qE2tV6/1)

The regex is as below

```
\$GPRMC,((?:[0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[0-9]+))?,|,)([A|V],|,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,|,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,|,)([0-9]+,|,)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,|,)(.*)
```

I am using regex.h header in C to compile the header and following is my code

```
#define NU [0-9]+
#define FLT NU\\.NU
regex_text= "\\$GPRMC,((?:NU)(?:\\.(?:NU))?,|,)([A|V],|,)(FLT,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)(FLT,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)(FLT,|,)(FLT,|,)(NU,|,)(FLT,|,)(.*)";
find_text = "$GPRMC,092751.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3371,W,0.06,31.66,280511,,,A*45";
```

Following is the error I am getting from GDB
GDB output:

```
23          int status = regcomp (r, regex_text, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
(gdb)
24          if (status != 0) {
(gdb)
26              regerror (status, r, error_message, MAX_ERROR_MSG);
(gdb)
27              printf ("Regex error compiling '%s': %s\n",
(gdb)
28                       regex_text, error_message);
(gdb)
27              printf ("Regex error compiling '%s': %s\n",
(gdb)
Regex error compiling '\$GPRMC,((?:NU)(?:\.(?:NU))?,|,)([A|V],|,)(FLT,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)(FLT,|,)([N|S|E|W],|,)(FLT,|,)(FLT,|,)(NU,|,)(FLT,|,)(.*)': Invalid preceding regular expression
29              return 1;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you are just trying to parse NMEA string, why are you not just splitting it based on comma. 1st index with NMEA verb or command and rest goes to it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `(?:NU)` is not supported by the POSIX standard.  On my system (Clang), if I distill the code, the error message says:

```
Regex error compiling '(?:NU)': repetition-operator operand invalid
```

You can fix this by using `REG_ENHANCED`  instead of `REG_EXTENDED`.  Or you can give up your non-capturing groups and use capturing groups instead:

```
"\\$GPRMC,((NU)...
```

By the way, `[N|S|E|W]` should probably be `[NSEW]`.

Comment: It seems REG_ENHANCED is not supported. Gcc is throwing an error "regex_check.c:23:42: error: 'REG_ENHANCED' undeclared (first use in this function)". I would like to keep the groups as well. Any help is appreciated